# Conditional PageBreak on a group in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am working on a report in which there is a need of conditional pageBreak on a group. I have tried to set the disabled property of PageBreak(of the group) but it's not working out for me. The disabled property is not working either i set it to true or give some expression but the BreakLocation property is working. Please help.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve ? Can you explain with the expected result ? May be image or something .

Comment: I Just want to set expression for the disabled Property of a PageBreak on a group.

Comment: I Just want to set expression for the disabled Property of a PageBreak on a group. For Ex: I have applied a group on a table on that i have used pageBreak after , now i want this PageBreak conditionally. So i googled that this can be achieved by setting expression in the disabled property but the disabled property is not working for me.

Comment: What is it not working ? Can show the expression ? Or what is your expected output and what are you getting ?

Comment: Simply setting the disabled property to true but page break is happening, which should not be if disabled is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression based page breaks, which, depending on your exact table setup, might be useful.

Basically, you set up a parameter to control whether page breaks are applied.

At the **Group** level, there are **Page Break** options - set the **Page Break** property to what you require, then set the **Disabled** property to be expression based, something like:

```
=IIf(Parameters!Break.Value, false, true)
```

[image]

[image]

This means the **Page Break** will only be applied of the **Break** parameter is set to true.

**UPDATE**

Set the expression for the Disables like,

```
= IIF(Parameters!Section.Value = 1,false,true)
```

And `BreakLocation` as `End`

Comment: Yes i tried the same as u said but this disabled property is not working out for me. Whether i set it to true or false it behaves the same.

Comment: You can set the expression as I explained above for that property

Comment: Did you tried to set the `BreakLocation` to `None` And also `Disabled` is not what you think it is. It just ignores the all other Page break values from the other places and follows what you set here. If you set it to `False` it will follow the other page break values from the report. If you set it to the `True` then it will follow what you set in the `BreakLocation`.

Comment: Like you said, If i set Disabled to false it will not follow my BreakLocation. I have set my BreakLocation to End and Disabled to False and the Page Break is happening and if i set the BreakLocation to None then nothing happens. So that means BreakLocation is working doesn't matter what the value of disabled property is.

Comment: Set the `Disabled` to `true` and `BreakLocation` to `None` if you don't want any pagebreaks

Comment: I want conditional pageBreak ForEx : If i have a variable named 'Section'.So i want if this section Value is 1 then Page Break else not

Comment: This is what i am trying from yesterday but didn't succeed yet. Disabled is looking like nothing for me because its not working anyhow. May be there is some problem in other area of report which i am not able to detect. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `IIF(Parameters!Section.Value = 1, false, true)`

You must set `BreakLocation = End`